# Is it possible to give a server read/write, but not delete permission to a Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'd like to give one of my servers read/write access to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, but not delete.

Basically I want the server to be able to upload backups, but if a malicious user ever breaks in, I don't want them able to delete the backups.

Do the Google Cloud Storage ACL's support this permission model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write permission for a bucket means user can modify it, both for creating and deleting files. There is nothing similar to "append mode only" on GCS currently. Have a look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#aclexamples) for a detailed explanation of GCS ACLs.